# How to display extra fields from a ManyToMany relation table when requesting a sub resource

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I need to display the **"skill"** of the **"drivers"** of specific **"cars"**, which comes from a relational table **"Relation_Car_Driver"**, this field should only appear for sub-resources calls **"/cars/:id/drivers"** and **"/drivers/:id/cars"**

I have 3 Tables :

- **Car** (id, model)
- **Driver** (id, name)
- **Relation_Car_Driver** (id, car_id, driver_id, skill)

My main API resources are :

- GET /cars
- GET /cars/:id
- GET /drivers
- GET /drivers/id

My API sub resources are :

- GET /drivers/:id/cars (list cars used by a specific driver)
- GET /cars/:id/drivers (list drivers for a specific car)

For those sub-resources calls i want to return the **"skill"** value coming from their relation !

**Entity Car** :

```php
# src/Entity/Car.php
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Car")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *          "drivers_get_subresource"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/cars/{id}/drivers"
 *          }
 *      }
 * )
 */
class Car
{
// ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Driver", inversedBy="cars")
     * @JoinTable(name="Relation_Car_Driver",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="driver_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @ApiSubresource(maxDepth=1)
     */
    private $drivers;
}
```

**Entity Driver** :

```php
# src/Entity/Driver.php
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Driver")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *          "cars_get_subresource"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/drivers/{id}/cars"
 *          }
 *      }
 * )
 */
class Driver
{
// ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Car", inversedBy="drivers")
     * @JoinTable(name="Relation_Car_Driver",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="driver_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @ApiSubresource(maxDepth=1)
     */
    private $cars;
}
```

**Entity Relation_Car_Driver** :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


/**
 * RelationCarDriver
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Relation_Car_Driver")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RelationCarDriver
{
// ..
    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="skill", type="int", nullable=true)
     */
    private $skill;
}
```

**Actual** result from **GET /drivers/:id/cars**:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Car",
  "@id": "/api/drivers/1/cars",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/cars/1",
      "@type": "Car",
      "id": 1,
      "model": "Mustang"
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/cars/2",
      "@type": "Car",
      "id": 2,
      "model": "Chevrolet"
    }
  ],
  "hydra:totalItems": 2
}
```

**Expected** result from **GET /drivers/:id/cars**:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Car",
  "@id": "/api/drivers/1/cars",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/cars/1",
      "@type": "Car",
      "id": 1,
      "model": "Mustang",
      "skill": 63
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/cars/2",
      "@type": "Car",
      "id": 2,
      "model": "Chevrolet",
      "skill": 13
    }
  ],
  "hydra:totalItems": 2
}
```

I have no clue how to achieve that ?
Thanks

Comment: doctrine can't handle adding an entity "as the many-to-many relation entity", instead, the relation entity (RelationCarDriver) must have two many-to-one relations, one to car, one to driver (and the many-to-many turn into one-to-many relations with the relation entity on both car and driver), then you probably have to add some logic to flatten that again... unless of course, api-platform has some logic that I don't know about, because I don't know api-platform

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and just found your post. I managed to solve this using a group (eg: api_read) defined on the "Driver" entity, and adding that group to the "skill" property wil print it flattend out with "car" entity, thus achieving what u were looking for